# Which is the "Android.App.ActivityManagerNative" equivalent class for xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, locale

I want to change the device language through my xamarin native application. I am easily able to do this using the following code in the android studio.

```
public static void changeLanguage()
        throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchFieldException {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class amnClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
    Object amn = null;
    Configuration config = null;

    // amn = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
    Method methodGetDefault = amnClass.getMethod("getDefault");
    methodGetDefault.setAccessible(true);
    amn = methodGetDefault.invoke(amnClass);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // getConfiguration moved from ActivityManagerNative to ActivityManagerProxy
        amnClass = Class.forName(amn.getClass().getName());
    }


    // config = amn.getConfiguration();

    Method methodGetConfiguration = amnClass.getMethod("getConfiguration");
    methodGetConfiguration.setAccessible(true);
    config = (Configuration) methodGetConfiguration.invoke(amn);

    // config.userSetLocale = true;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class configClass = config.getClass();
    Field f = configClass.getField("userSetLocale");
    f.setBoolean(config, true);

    Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN");

    // set the locale to the new value
    config.locale = locale;

    // amn.updateConfiguration(config);
    Method methodUpdateConfiguration = amnClass.getMethod("updateConfiguration", Configuration.class);
    methodUpdateConfiguration.setAccessible(true);
    methodUpdateConfiguration.invoke(amn, config);
}
```

I want to do the same through Xamarin. But in xamarin it throws the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Android.App.ActivityManagerNative"
```

Please let me know which class can I use in Xamarin for achieving the same?

Comment: I tried to translate your code to C# and I couldn't reproduce this problem, my mono.Android version is 4.0.30319, VS 2017, jdk 1.8.0_144, compile target: Android 8.0, tested device: emulator with Android 7.0. But I found someone else with native java android who had the same problem, he created fake class in build path to bypass this issue, but since I could't reproduce this issue, I'm not sure if this solution helps.

Comment: Hi, if you were not able to reproduce the issue that means were you able to change the device language from your code written in Xamarin?

Comment: I didn't tested that far, I met problem with last line of code, and it suggested that I don't have permission, I've added the permissions in manifest, but after researching, it seems that using this method, the app should be installed as a system app, I didn't install that, but the code is fine by my side.

Comment: I am also using Mono.Android 4.0.30319 and VS 2017. But I am getting ClassNotFoundException. Can you please guide me where am I going wrong? Or can you please share your project with me? Also in this documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.App/ , there is no such class mentioned.

Comment: I've wrote an answer to post my code and my project, you may have a check. This class is inside Android SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please guide me where am I going wrong? Or can you please share your project with me?

Here is my code:

```
var amnClass = Java.Lang.Class.ForName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
Java.Lang.Object amn = null;
Configuration config = null;

var methodGetDefault = amnClass.GetMethod("getDefault");
methodGetDefault.Accessible = true;
amn = methodGetDefault.Invoke(amnClass);

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
    amnClass = Java.Lang.Class.ForName(amn.Class.Name);
}

var methodGetConfiguration = amnClass.GetMethod("getConfiguration");
methodGetConfiguration.Accessible = true;
config = methodGetConfiguration.Invoke(amn) as Configuration;

var configClass = config.Class;
var f = configClass.GetField("userSetLocale");
f.SetBoolean(config, true);

Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN");

config.Locale = locale;

var methodUpdateConfiguration = amnClass.GetMethod("updateConfiguration", Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Configuration)));
methodUpdateConfiguration.Accessible = true;
try
{
    methodUpdateConfiguration.Invoke(amn, config);
}
catch (InvocationTargetException ee)
{
    var error = ee.TargetException;
}
```

And here is my [demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/ActivityManagerNative-Test).

Comment: I was using Xamarin Android.App.ActivityManagerNative. But I was supposed to use the class from Android SDK. It works for me now. Thanks a lot.